# Can I limit refile targets with helm using a regular expression?

Tags: helm, regular-expressions, org-refile

I would like to be able to use regular expressions in helm when selecting a refile target following an `org-refile` call. For example, if my list of targets includes

```
1. H1/
1. H1/P1/
1. H1/P1/C1/
1. H1/P1/C1/S2/
```

I would like to be able to type in C1/$ to limit my options to

```
1. H1/P1/C1/
```

only. This does not seem to work, and typing C1/$ returns no matches. If I search for C1 my selection gets limited to

```
1. H1/P1/C1/
1. H1/P1/C1/S2/
```

i.e. every target that includes C1.

I can do this kind of filtering in helm following a `helm-find-file` but I can't get it to work in the refile operation.

Is what I want do-able?